# calling a function from within a class "collate"

Tags: java, class

how do I change my call to the function collate, I want it to print out  collate(“hello”, “there”) is “htehlelroe”.

```
public class Collate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = new String("hello");
        String b = new String("there");          
    }

    public String collate(String a, String b) {
        String collate = new String();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            collate = collate + a.substring(i);
            collate = collate + b.substring(i);
            collate(a, b);
            System.out.println(collate);
        }
        return collate;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are infinitely calling collate, as you are always calling it with the same arguments (a,b) inside itself, while not chaning any state. Your program will crash if you execute it. Also, if you want to call collate from the main method, you must declare it static or instantiate a Collate object on which you can call collate. (static methods cannot call non-static methods)

Comment: also replace `substring(i)` with `charAt(i)`

Comment: You unnecessarily create recursion (method calling itself).  Your `collate(a,b)` should be inside `main` and also, `collate()` method itself should be `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```
public class Collate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = new String("hello");
        String b = new String("there");          
        System.out.print(collate(a,b));
    }

    public static String collate(String a, String b) {
        String collate = new String();
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
            collate += a.charAt(i);
            collate += b.charAt(i);
        }

        return collate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want.

What did we have to change in your code:

- collate must be static if we want to call it directly from another static method, i.e, main
- you were recursively calling collate with the same arguments. In fact, we just want to collate the reminder of the strings (once we have taken the first character
- you simply assumed a and b to be of equal length and just tried to loop over the length of a. You should always state your assumptions about the arguments of a method. If you had called your collate method with a longer than b, you probably would not have gotten what you wanted
- new String("something") should not be called. This will create a new instance of a string type. Strings in Java are immutable, so there is no reason to do this. While new String() does not influence the semantics of your program, it can have a severe impact on its performance, especially, if you are creating strings in a loop.

  public class Collate {

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String a = "hello";
      String b = "there";
      System.out.println(collate(a, b));
  }
  public static String collate(String a, String b) {
      if (a.length() != b.length())
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot collate strings of unequal size");
      if (a.isEmpty())
          return "";
      else {
          String collate = "";
          StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
          char firstCharacterOfA = a.charAt(0);
          char firstCharacterOfB = b.charAt(0);
          result.append(firstCharacterOfA);
          result.append(firstCharacterOfB);
          result.append(collate(a.substring(1), b.substring(1)));
          return result.toString();
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Edit: Note that recursion can potentially kill your application here. If the strings you pass are large, you can run into a StackOverflow. Also, performance can suffer, because a method call has some small costs.

If you write your method iterative, e.g., using a for-loop as Ankush did, you will have no such problems.