# Alternating characters of two different inputs

Tags: java

I want to take two strings and alternate the characters into a new string using a for method.

Example: "two" and "one"

Result: "townoe"

This is what I have so far, and I really don't know how to finish it.

```
public class Alternator {   
    String alternate(String a, String b) {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            s += i;
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This seems like your homework.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944119/calling-a-function-from-within-a-class-collate/25944205#25944205

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Alternator{
    public static String alternate(String a, String b){
        String s = "";
        int i = 0;
        while (i < a.length() && i < b.length()){
            s += a.charAt(i) +""+ b.charAt(i); 
            i++;
        }
        while (i < a.length() ){
            s += a.charAt(i); 
            i++;
        }
        while (i < b.length()){
            s += b.charAt(i); 
            i++;
        }
        return s;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String a = "two", b = "one";
        String s = Alternator.alternate(a,b);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

To use for loop instead of while loop, simply remove all while lines with for lines like the following, then remove the i++ line from each while loop

```
for(; i < a.length() && i < b.length(); i++){
//the inside of the loop MINUS THE LINE i++ 
}
for(; i < a.length(); i++){
//the inside of the loop MINUS THE LINE i++ 
}
for(; i < b.length(); i++){
//the inside of the loop MINUS THE LINE i++ 
}
```

Comment: 1 error found:
[line: 21]
Error: non-static method alternate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context         <-----This is at "String s = alternate(a,b);"

Comment: you ran the code before i modified it. run my answer (current) again. the bug was fixed before you gave me that -1 vote.

Comment: I didn't give you the -1 vote, but yes this modified code seems to work. But how could I write this code with a for method and not a while method?

Comment: I gave you that downvote. I don't think it's helpful to provide pure code like this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Come on, the question is fairly basic.There is little to explain. Instead, the learner could just look at the code and figure out what it does! It's like learning programming from books in the olden days

Comment: Hey Sotirios, I'm trying to understand the problem. I'm not here to just take some code for my solution. I want to understand how to finish my code.

Comment: Don't help those that don't deserve it.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: help whoever you want. I'll judge if I find your answer helpful.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Jerry, juding by his rep, is a newcomer, perhaps he deserves some leniency and time to learn more.

Comment: @Tuan333 Thank you for understanding. I've been staring at a book for hours to try and understand for loops, but I have gone nowhere. What is wrong with human help?

Comment: @Jerry That changes everything, you should've mentioned from the beginning you were having trouble understanding the for loop

Comment: Read the Help Center. Stack Overflow has a purpose and it isn't to do your work for you. You haven't even asked a question. You just dumped a requirement.

Comment: So I should have asked how to execute a for loop to alternate characters of two strings?

Comment: @Jerry, Yeah, that would've been a better question

Answer (score 1):

Here is some compact way of doing that:

```
String alternate(String a, String b) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    int smallerStringLength = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < smallerStringLength; i++) {
        builder.append(a.charAt(i));
        builder.append(b.charAt(i));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Or even more optimized:

```
String alternate(String first, String second) {
    char[] firstChars = first.toCharArray();
    char[] secondChars = second.toCharArray();

    int smallerCharsCount = Math.min(firstChars.length, secondChars.length);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(smallerCharsCount * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < smallerCharsCount; i++) {
        builder.append(firstChars[i]);
        builder.append(secondChars[i]);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work if string are of same length or of the different lengths.

```
static void mergeStrings(String a, String b) {
    StringBuilder mergedBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    char[] aCharArr = a.toCharArray();
    char[] bCharArr = b.toCharArray();

    int minLength = aCharArr.length >= bCharArr.length ? bCharArr.length : aCharArr.length;

    for (int i=0; i<minLength; i++) {
        mergedBuilder.append(aCharArr[i]).append(bCharArr[i]);
    }

    if(minLength < aCharArr.length) {
        mergedBuilder.append(a.substring(minLength));
    }
    else{
        mergedBuilder.append(b.substring(minLength));
    }
    Systemout.println(mergedBuilder.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String alternate(String a, String b){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    final int greaterLength = a.length() > b.length() ? a.length() : b.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < greaterLength; i++){
        if (i < a.length()) {
            builder.append(a.charAt(i));
        }
        if (i < b.length()) {
            builder.append(b.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

It uses the [`String.charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) method to obtain letters, and a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to create the string.

(When given two strings of non-equal length, this returns an alternation of the first two chars, and then does just the remaining string.  EG: `Hello` and `Hi` --> `HHeillo`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two strings are the exact same length, you can do the following.  If they are different length, then currently your prompt doesn't say how you want the resultant string to be set up.

```
public class Alternator {
    String alternate(String a, String b) {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 2*a.length(); i++) {
            if (i%2==0) // modular arithmetic to alternate
                s += a.charAt(i/2); // Note the integer division
            else
                s += b.charAt(i/2);
        }
        System.out.println(s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, even easier, but the index i doesn't mark the length of your string s:

```
public class Alternator {
    String alternate(String a, String b) {
        String s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
            s += a.charAt(i);
            s += b.charAt(i);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments I've read, you are having trouble understanding for loops, and how to use them with strings.

For loops are most often used to iterate over arrays, or to perform a task a given number of times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

This would give the output

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

For loops start at the value of the initializer, the first thing you put in `int i = 0;`

They then check the expression, the second part of the for loop, and if it returns true, it executes all of the code inside the braces. `i < 5;`

Once it has done that, it runs the incrementor, the last part of the for loop. `i++`

After that, it checks the expression again. I guess you can see where this is going. Until the expression returns false, everything inside the curly braces of the for loop gets executed over and over again.

Strings can be iterated over with a for loop, but you can't reference it like an array using `array[index]`. You have to either convert it into an array, using `.toCharArray()` on your String, and return the result to an empty char array `char[]`, or use the `.charAt(index)` method on your string.

This code will go over a string, and output each character, one by one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(myString.charAt(i));
}
```

If the string had a value of "Hello", the output would be:

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

Using this, instead of outputting the characters using `System.out.println();`, we can put them into an empty string, using +=:

```
myOtherString += myString.charAt(i);
```

That means, if we want to go over two Strings at a time, and alternate them, like you do, we can iterate over two strings at the same time, and add them to a new string:

```
myAlternatedString += myString.charAt(i); 
myAlternatedString += myOtherString.charAt(i);
```

if MyString was still "Hello" and myOtherString was "World", the new string would be:

```
Hweolrllod
```

Answer (score 0):

following code reads 2 different inputs and merges into a single string.

public class PrintAlternnateCharacterString {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = in.next();
    String b = in.next();

    String mergedString = "";

    int lenA = a.length();
    int lenB = b.length();
    if (lenA >= lenB) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lenA; i++) {
            if (i < lenB) {
                mergedString += a.charAt(i) + "" + b.charAt(i);

            } else {
                mergedString += a.charAt(i);
            }
        }

    }
    if (lenB > lenA) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lenB; i++) {
            if (i < lenA) {
                mergedString += a.charAt(i) + "" + b.charAt(i);

            } else {
                mergedString += b.charAt(i);
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println("the merged string is-->" + mergedString);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

public static String stringConcate(String str1,String str2){

```
    String str3="";
    if(str1!=null && str2!=null && !str1.isEmpty() && !str2.isEmpty()){
            if(str1.length()==str2.length()){
                for(int i=0;i<=str1.length()-1;i++){
                    str3+=str1.charAt(i);
                    str3+=str2.charAt(i);

                }
            }
            if(str1.length()>str2.length()){
                for(int i=0;i<=str1.length()-1;i++){
                    str3+=str1.charAt(i);
                    if(i<str2.length()){
                        str3+=str2.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(str2.length()>str1.length()){
                for(int i=0;i<=str2.length()-1;i++){
                    if(i<str1.length()){
                        str3+=str1.charAt(i);
                    }
                    str3+=str2.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return str3;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str1 = "one"; String str2 = "two";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < str1.length() && i < str2.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(str1.charAt(i)).append(str2.charAt(i));
    }
    for(; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(str1.charAt(i));
    }
    for(; i < str2.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(str2.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println("result  = " + sb.toString());// otnweo
```

This will handle for different length too

Answer (score 0):

This could be donw with very simple `if...else`.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] one = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] two = { 44, 55, 66, 77, 88 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(alternate(one, two)));
}

public static int[] alternate(int[] one, int[] two) {
    int[] res = new int[one.length + two.length];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            res[i] = j < one.length ? one[j++] : two[k++];
        else
            res[i] = k < two.length ? two[k++] : one[j++];
    }

    return res;
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 44, 2, 55, 3, 66, 77, 88]
```